# How to split and trim audio files in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, audio

I need to build a feature in my react.js app that allows users to trim and split the audio files they upload. I know this can be done, as web apps such as Youtube allow editing of video/audio files right in the browser. But I'm not sure where to start. Would appreciate any ideas.

Would also welcome suggestions as to how to do this on the backend with node.js, i.e. modules to use, etc.

Comment: I've never done anything like this, but I don't think you need much more than the [HTMLAudioElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement), which has all of the apis for controlling playback. Simulate trimming through your interface in browser and then send the bounds to your backend for the actual creation of the trimmed file.

Comment: @AlexGuerra What would you use to split/trim the audio files on the back end? I have node server.

Comment: I'd probably shell out to ffmpeg.